# Parse reply/quote and make it a hyperlink ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex

I'm working on a messageboard and I'd like to have the following reply/quote system:

```
@5432 //post number
This is a reply to a post
@5647
This is a reply to another post
```

This is plain text, server-side I want to replace it so it ends like this:

```
<a href="#5432>@5432</a>
...
```

I think the regex would be `^@\d+`, but I don't know how to implement it, especially with multiple ocurrences.

This ASP.NET + C#, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in c#:

```
string str = @"@5432 //post number
            This is a reply to a post
            @5647
            This is a reply to another post";

Regex.Replace(str, @"(@)(\d+)", @"<a href=""#$2"">$1$2</a>")
```